# Gorenstein Rings

Tags: commutative-algebra

My question refers to a notation in following excerpt: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0DW6

[image]

What is $A[0]$?

Answer (score 0):

The complex whose 0th term is the ring $A$, and all of whose other terms are $0$, with $0$ maps everywhere.